# Show green tick after first job in workflow completes

Tags: github, circleci

I have recently updated a CircleCI workflow that originally just had a test job, to have an optional deploy step that requires manual approval.

Previously on GitHub, the commit would get a green tick when tests were completed. However, now since there is a pending job in the workflow, it never changes to a tick unless the deploy job is also executed.

Is there any way to specify that I only care about the test job and give a tick once that job is complete, rather than waiting for the entire workflow to complete?

This screenshot illustrates the problem (notice the icon next to the commit sha1 is still "pending"):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is still not possible in the CircleCI/GitHub integration (April 2022).

You can comment/vote [here](https://circleci.canny.io/cloud-feature-requests/p/show-overall-all-checks-have-passed-status-in-github-even-on-builds-with-incompl) or [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/pull-request-checks-on-github-are-stuck-in-in-progress-because-of-type-approval-step/26617) to hopefully help moving this up in priority...